# Feature Engineering/FS

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest, feature-engineering

I've a dataset which consists of 33 features.

Out of which first 32 features are latitude & longitude positions for 16 machines at 16 different locations (16latitude & 16 longitude values).

The target is sum of power generated by 16 machines at 16 different locations.

The task is to build regression model using these 32 features to predict total power generated.

My question is what approach should i take to solve this task. How to find whether the positions of these machines matters a lot?

Can i build random forest model, if yes then whether the positions will not be lost? (considering it will be built on subset of features)

e.g, if i build simple regression, all the features will be taken from 1 to 32 as it is, but if i build random forest it might consider any feature randomnly from 32.

Comment: A random forest model won't lose features. Individual trees in the forest are built using a subset of features, but each feature will be used in some of the trees.

Comment: Yes, that's true but all the features will be selected randomly right(no matter what their index position is). They won't be picked as per their actual index position in data frame

Comment: How many samples do you have? Do you also have time as a feature? If you do, then you may have a spatiotemporal forecasting problem.

Comment: Is this wind power, or something similar?